# Facebook like button issue image, title, description

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-like, title

I have created a Facebook like button on my website 6 months ago it was working fine and showing image, title and description while posting the comment. But now from 2 days it's not showing any information showing  shared URL instead of the image, title and description while posting comment.
Here is my website link.
https://www.whatyourneighbourpaid.com
Please see at the footer for share icon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your page in the [Facebook Debuger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://www.whatyourneighbourpaid.com/) (AKA linter)?

It says:

> **Errors That Must Be Fixed**
>
> Object Base Domain Not Allowed:   Object at URL
>   'https://us.whatyourneighbourpaid.com/' of type 'website' is invalid
>   because the domain 'us.whatyourneighbourpaid.com' is not allowed for
>   the specified application id '391421600878949'. You can verify your
>   configured 'App Domain' at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/apps/391421600878949.

My guess is that in the app settings the url you used is not *us.whatyourneighbourpaid.com*, maybe *www.whatyourneighbourpaid.com* or just plain *whatyourneighbourpaid.com*?
If that's the case then just add this to the App Domains in the app settings and things should work fine.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for reply.

I have added following setting in Apps.
Site URL: https://www. whatyourneighbourpaid.com /
App Domain: whatyourneighbourpaid.com

It’s giving me error message  “Error Parsing URL:Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.”  When I try to debug the url using this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

Please let me know what is wrong from my side? It’s very urgent for me.

Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what to tell you, your page is problematic.. even when I try to curl it i get an empty response, if I try to load it in the web browser it takes A LOT of time for it to load. I think that the facebook scraper has a timeout and because of that you get that error. You need to check why it takes so long for your page to load.

Comment: Hi,
I think issue is not with page load.I tried with other url on my website it's showing same error message. Is there any other way to debug? Can you take a look of view source of my page and let me know? This is very urgent for me thanks :)

Comment: What "other url" did you test? Can you add it here so I can try as well? I meant that you have server problems, or something like that, meaning that (this is a guess) all of your pages load extremely slowly, and since the facebook scraper has a timeout you get that error.

Comment: Yes, this page is super slow as well, you can check it here for example: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/w2R4vwLTN/https://www.whatyourneighbourpaid.com/about_us. it says "Your website is slower than 81% of all tested websites". You need to figure out why it's so slow. When you improve that then the facebook scraper timeout won't affect you.

Comment: Try this is my sample test page
https://whatyourneighbourpaid.com/facebookshare5.php

Comment: Yeah, this one loads way faster, but the error persists. I'm not sure why that happens, maybe facebook added your domain to some sort of "blocked" list due to the unreasonable response time they faced in the past. There are a few bugs about this like: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/146399405469364/ and more questions in here. You might want to consider following those. Another thing is that you keep using https urls, but your certificate is not valid.

Comment: Ok let me check.
your certificate is not valid? How to check this one? Is valid or not?

Comment: Oh wait, my bad, your certificate is verified. When using *curl* it was complaining but in using the browser it looks fine. It's probably a problem at my end.

Comment: Ok, Please let me know if you found any hint for my problem.
Thanks

Comment: As I said, besides the part about the certificate, you should follow the bug reports about this problem (there are a few) and other threads regarding this same issue.